# Direct sum of groups vs product

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I've got a problem with the finish of the answer of the following problem:
[Homology of connected sum of real projective spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652721/homology-of-connected-sum-of-real-projective-spaces?rq=1).

How is that $(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z})/(2,\dots,2)\mathbb{Z}$ with $n$ twos is equal to $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$?

$\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}^n$,since $n$ is finite and we have finite sequences, right? Or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm gonna delete my question in a sec, it's indeed the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ that contains $e=(1,1,\dots,1)$. Using that basis, it is clear that $$\mathbb{Z}^n/(2,\dots,2)\mathbb{Z}=(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z})/(0^{n-1}\oplus2e\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$$